# Program installation - Issue with the default location

Tags: c#, vb.net, installation, directory, default

I'm a beginner. I recently developed an application in C#. Now I wanna develop its setup.

I read a few articles online, followed them, found it very easy. I also changed the default location of application folder from `C:\Program Files` to `C:\`. My application folder is containing a few folders besides exe and dlls which I added manually.

Now here the problem starts, when I install the application and change the location say from `c:\` to `d:\`, my files (all files including exe and dll) are going to user's given location. But my folders (all folders in application folder) are going to `c:\` (which is default location given while creating setup). But I want output files and that folders at same location

Where did I go wrong???

Comment: Did you hardcode the `c:\...` path somewhere?

Comment: is there any other way of making a setup

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[TARGETDIR]` in your **Path** instead of hard-coding `C:` or `D:`.

`[TARGETDIR]` will return the folder that chosen on Setup steps by user.